# Does flossing make me fleishig?

Tags: food, meat

If a person ate meat and after 6 hours (or whatever that person's custom is) she then flosses and finds minute traces of food on the floss is she considered to once again to 'be fleishig' ie need to start the waiting period between meat and milk over?